# Where is the documentation for the current textcomp package?

Tags: packages, documentation

If I Google for "latex textcomp documentation", the most relevant hit is the CTAN textcomp page, which says:

> Note that the pack­age has been adopted as part of the LATEX
>   dis­tri­bu­tion; the ref­er­ence here is to the orig­i­nal pack­age,
>   which is now lit­tle used (if at all).

But I cannot seem to find where the official, current, documentation is for the `textcomp` package that comes with LaTeX. The same goes for a number of other packages, such as `fontenc`.

Does documentation exist for these packages? Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: `texdoc textcomp` yields `LaTeX font encodings` as document, with some examples in it, but try http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf too

Comment: If you want to know about the 'symbols' the package grants access to, Christian's link is the way to go.

Comment: In my case: `Sorry, no documentation found for textcomp.
If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.`

Answer (score 9):

The intended user documentation is `encguide.pdf` as returned by `texdoc textcomp`. If you want the actual documented source then the file is generated from `ltoutenc.dtx` in the base latex distribution (the same source as the `fontenc` package) If you run pdflatex on `ltoutenc.dtx` (in texmf-dist/doc/latex/base in texlive) then you will get ltoutenc.pdf, this file isn't normally made in the distribution.

Alternatively, as other parts of  `ltoutenc.dtx`  are included in the format, you can see the typeset form as chapter l of source2e.pdf so  `texdoc source2e` page 69.

Comment: while this is all true, i feel that `encguide` leaves too many links un-tied, and i was loth to hand it over after i'd put the basic thing together.  frank made a lot of changes afterwards, but it was not imo complete even then, and it hasn't changed since.  (one of the problems is i'm so slow...)

Comment: I am using miktex, and I can't find `ltoutenc.dtx` nor the documentation of `textcomp`.  `source2e` doesn't have the commands of `textcomp`, so where can I search for its commands and options?