# Can you provide a link to a font or typeface containing a double bar dollar sign?

Tags: fonts, symbols, typefaces

Can anybody refer me to a font file or typeface that contains the proper US dollar sign?

A problem with most typefaces is that they contain a generic dollar sign, containing a single vertical bar. A US dollar sign contains two vertical bars. The commonly used alternatives are $us9.99 or us$8.88.

*Explanation*: The original US dollar sign was a monogram of US. It consisted of a sanserif capital S, with a narrow sanserif capital U centered on top of it. Later, the bottom of the U was removed.

Comment: Have you tried  `\usepackage{textcomp}` with `\textdollaroldstyle`?  [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) can be a great resource.

Answer (score 5):

You can often find the fonts you want by searching on [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\textdollaroldstyle
\end{document}
```

(Remark : `textcomp` package is obsolete, it is directly integrated in recent LaTeX versions, you can then drop the `\usepackage{textcomp}` line. More informations here: [Where is the documentation for the current textcomp package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222457/132405)
).

[image]

That may seem like a lot to write out, so in your preamble you can put

```
\let\dollar\textdollaroldstyle
```

and then you can write

```
\dollar3.50
```

in you document and get the proper symbol.

Comment: or even \let\$\textdollaroldstyle

Comment: Even simpler: http://write-math.com/search/?search=dollar

Comment: @moose The only thing is on that site it seems you have to have some idea of what to call the symbol.  On detexify, you just need to know how to draw it.

Comment: @A.Ellett I am the developer of write-math.com. And no, you don't need to do text search. I also have a "search by draw" (which supports 374 symbols and works better / faster than Detexify). In total, I have more than 1111 symbols. Every symbol has a description page which often links to other symbols / mentions variations of the symbol.

Comment: @moose Good to know then.  :-)

Comment: @A.Ellett In the next weeks I want to make the symbol pages get a version history so that it is like StackOverflow / Wikipedia. I also plan to add tags so that symbols can be grouped (e.g. cyrillic, arrow, currency, ...)

Answer (score 1):

I was always taught that the dollar sign was originally created as a superposition of "U" and "S", a uniquely American symbol.  Thus, for a *really old* version of the symbol, I build it here from scratch.

Here, I show the serif and sans versions of the "S".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\def\origdollar{%
  \stackengine{-1.6pt}{S}{\scalebox{.33}[1.4]{\sffamily U}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\def\origdollarsans{%
  \stackengine{-1.4pt}{\sffamily S}{\scalebox{.38}[1.35]{\sffamily U}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
\begin{document}
\origdollar 5 \textit{vs.} \origdollarsans 10
\end{document}
```

[image]

As far as pre-existing fonts:

http://www.dafont.com/benjamin-franklin.font

[image]

http://www.dafont.com/butterbrotpapier.font

[image]

http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Cantabile/

[image]